# Did 3 laws of dialectics affirm themselves true from the current prospective of physics and social science?

Tags: philosophy-of-science, hegel

There are 3 universal laws derived from Hegel's dialectics which are claimed to reveal the essential features of any developing phenomenon, no matter to what field of activity it may belong:
1.The law of the unity and conflict of opposites;
2.The law of the passage of quantitative changes into qualitative changes;
3.The law of the negation of the negation

Did those 3 laws affirm themselves true by examples from the current prospective of physics and social science?

Comment: Those are three ["laws of dialectical materialism"](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Ultrahuman/TQMUEAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=.The+law+of+the+unity+and+conflict+of+opposites%3B+2.The+law+of+the+passage+of+quantitative+changes+into+qualitative+changes%3B+3.The+law+of+the+negation+of+the+negation&pg=PT64&printsec=frontcover), they are not Hegel's, and they are too vague to have any definite truth value. At best, they can be heuristics for systematizing one's worldview that are useful to some and less so to others. The same applies to Hegel's own dialectical method.

Comment: @Conifold The works of Hegel are cited as the source for the dialectics in the "dialectical materialism", while works of Feuerbach are cited as the source for the materialism.

Comment: Let's put it this way, Marx and Engels treated what they took from Hegel... creatively. Dialectical materialism is their own brainchild far removed from both Hegel and Feuerbach. Hegel had no such "laws", and even the dialectical triad (thesis-antithesis-synthesis) they ascribed to him is taken from Fichte and was never adopted by Hegel, see [SEP](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/hegel-dialectics/#WhyDoesHegeUseDial).

Comment: They are "general" philosophical assumptions: there is no way to "prove" them from a scientific point of view.

Comment: @conifold, how about posting a complete answer here? my attempt earned me -2 and a tongue-lashing from philip klocking. I think you can do better...

Comment: @nielsnielsen Questions with flawed presuppositions are best left unanswered. If the OP wants to ask a transformed question that takes into account the new information they can do so.